# Passing list dict to template not working django

Tags: python, html, django, list, templates

I am trying to pass a list called eligable so that I can display on my website but when I run my website it does not display the list. I do not understand what is wrong.

code:

```
def specificDate(response):
    empName = employeeName.objects.all()
    eligable = []
    if 'checkEmployee' in response.POST:
        n = response.POST.get("nameEmployee")
        specDate = response.POST.get("date")
        if employeeName.objects.filter(employee=n).exists() and Name.objects.filter(date=specDate).exists():
            emp = employeeName.objects.get(employee=n)
            t = Name.objects.get(name=emp, date=specDate)
            overT = Name.objects.filter(name=emp, overtime=True)
            for item in overT:
                eligable.append(item.date)
            checkIn = t.timeIn.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            checkOut = t.timeOut.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            datee = datetime.strptime(specDate,'%Y-%m-%d')
            print("Here:: ",t.date)
            print("Month:: ",datee.month)
            messages.info(response, checkIn + ' - ' + checkOut)
            return redirect('/specificDate')
        else:
            messages.info(response, 'Name does not exist')
    else: 
        pass
    return render(response, "main/specificDate.html",  context={"empName":empName, "eligable":eligable})
```

This is the html to print my list:

```
{% for item in eligable %}
<div class="pad3">
    {{item}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you added `{% endfor %}` below the div

Comment: @Poornaka yes I missed it when copying the code sry

Comment: The problem is that the POST request data cannot go when you redirect

Comment: try returning a normal render

Comment: its okay I tried emril's answer and It works now. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two return statements in your code:

```
    return redirect('/specificDate')
```

and

```
    return render(response, "main/specificDate.html",  context={"empName":empName, "eligable":eligable})
```

The first one is just redirecting without populating context.

The second one does populate context but is reached only when `eligable` is empty.

I think changing the first return to the second one should solve it.

edit: and you are missing {% endfor %} here. But it should give you an error if you miss it in your complete code.

Comment: so I should change return redirect(....) to return render(....)?

Comment: Yes. When redirecting, you aren't passing any info to the next page.